# How to align horizontal buttons to the right?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I would like to make a simple panel with buttons that are placed horizontally and aligned to the right. Willing to align it to the left I can easily do this like that :

```
.button {
    float:left;
    background-color: #55cc66;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
//......
    <div id="switcher">
        <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
        <div class="button selected" id="switcher-default">
        Default
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="switcher-narrow">
        Narrow Column
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="switcher-large">
        Large Print
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I do the same with `float:right` it obviously aligns it to the right but in inverted order. I have also tried `text-align: right`, `position: absolute; right:150;` and `position: fixed; right:150;`. The last two align to the right but awkwardly overlap the 'buttons'.

How can I achieve this then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove floats and align the container of your "buttons" to the right with the property `text-align`.
You don't want your heading to be aligned to the right so you've to cancel it with `text-align: left;`.

One problem remains: you're using non-semantic `div` when what you really want are buttons. You should use ... `button` elements (or maybe `input[type"button|image|submit"]`).
These ones are focusable and are made for an action taking place when clicked (with mouse, keyboard or tap).
Back to these `div`: they are displayed as blocks by default, you've to change for `inline-block` - IE8+.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/YZaRW/

Comment: Thanks. +1 For jsfiddle. Really great site :)

Answer (score 0):

Leave the class .button with float left, wrap all your buttons with another division (btn_wrapper) and add a specific width to it and float right. Just make sure that all your buttons fit inside the wrapper

```
.btn_wrapper{
width:300px;
float:right
} 

<div id="switcher">
        <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
<div class="btn_wrapper">        
<div class="button selected" id="switcher-default">
        Default
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="switcher-narrow">
        Narrow Column
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="switcher-large">
        Large Print
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
```